# Properties of non-minimal graded free resolutions of an homogeneous ideal

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, betti-numbers

I would like to know if the following fact is true.

Let $K$ be a field, $S=K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ be the standard polynomial ring, and $I$ be a graded ideal of $S$.

It's known that, up to isomorphism, there is only one minimal graded free $S$-resolution of $I$,
$$
{\bf F}:0\rightarrow F_s\rightarrow F_{s-1}\rightarrow \dots \rightarrow F_0\rightarrow I\rightarrow 0,
$$
with $F_i=\bigoplus_{j}S(-j)^{\beta_{i,j}}$, where $\beta_{i,j}$ are the graded Betti numbers of $I$.

My question is, given any other $S$-resolution of $I$, non-minimal,
$$
{\bf G}:0\rightarrow G_r\rightarrow G_{r-1}\rightarrow \dots \rightarrow G_0\rightarrow I\rightarrow 0,
$$
with $G_i=\bigoplus_{j}S(-j)^{\gamma_{i,j}}$, is it true that $\gamma_{i,j}\ge\beta_{i,j}$ for all $i,j\ge 0$?

If it is not true in general, is it true for some special kind of non-minimal resolution?

Does some references exist in the literature?

Comment: There is a result is that the minimality of $F$ is equivalent to any quasi-isomorphism $F \to G$ being injective, i.e. the maps are injective in every degree. (Proposition 1.1.2(iv) here: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-0346-0329-4_1).

Comment: I still don't see how this answer my question. Could you please elaborate on it a bit more

Comment: I don't know either if it fully answers your question, but it might give a partial answer. If $R^m \to R^n$ is an injective map of free $R$-modules, then $m \leq n$ (both $m,n$ are positive integers). Apply this to $S(j)^{\gamma_{i,j}} \to S(j)^{\beta_{i,j}}$ in each degree, and see if it gives what you are looking for. With the assumption that $F \to G$ is a quasi-isomorphism, you get injective maps everywhere.

Comment: I also want to add that I have been told that this is an equivalence, which can be seen by tensoring the resolutions with $k=S/(x_1, ..., x_n)$ and use Nakayama's lemma, but I haven't been able to prove it. It is possible that some more assumptions are needed, but I have had this question too and haven't got a better answer than what I linked above.